# WP - Shortcode to query custom post type and display according to custom meta value

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I've set up a plugin which creates a custom post type ('Programmes') along with a taxonomy and some custom meta. I have a custom meta value called 'broadcast-date' and I'm trying to create a short code which will display only the programmes that have a broadcast date equal to or greater than today (to show a schedule of upcoming programmes).

At the moment I've only got the posts displaying, I'm not sure where to start with the date query. Here's what I've got so far:

```
add_shortcode('programme-schedule', 'programme_schedule_shortcode');
function programme_schedule_shortcode($atts, $content){
  extract(shortcode_atts(array( // a few default values
   'posts_per_page' => '-1',
   'post_type' => 'programmes')
   , $atts));

  global $post;

  $posts = new WP_Query($atts);
  $output = '';
    if ($posts->have_posts())
        while ($posts->have_posts()):
            $posts->the_post();
        $out = '<p>' . get_the_title() . '</p>';
    endwhile;
  else
    return;

  wp_reset_query();
  return html_entity_decode($out);
}
```

What can I add to this so that it will only display upcoming programmes?

Thanks :)

EDIT:

Turns out that code wasn't working either, I'm now working with this (still only getting the posts at the moment, not filtering them):

```
add_shortcode( 'hiblio-schedule', 'rmcc_post_listing_shortcode1' );
function rmcc_post_listing_shortcode1( $atts ) {
    ob_start();
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'programmes',
    ) );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
        <ul class="schedule-listing">
            <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
            <li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </li>
            <?php endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </ul>
    <?php $myvariable = ob_get_clean();
    return $myvariable;
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

EDIT2:

Here's my current code:

```
add_shortcode( 'hiblio-schedule', 'hiblio_schedule_shortcode' );
function hiblio_schedule_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $todaysDate = date("Y/m/d");
    $date = '24/12/2014';//get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'broadcast-date', true );
    $parts = explode('/',$date);
    $newDate = $parts[2]."-".$parts[1]."-".$parts[0];
    ob_start();
    $query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'programmes',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
        'key' => 'broadcast-date',
        'value' => $todaysDate  , //The date what you want...
        'compare'   => '>='
        ),
    ),
    ));
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    ?>
        <ul class="schedule-listing">
            <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
            <li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </li>
            <?php endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </ul>
    <?php $myvariable = ob_get_clean();
    return $myvariable;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `meta_query` or key/value pairs. Read **[here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)**.

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'programmes',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'broadcast-date',
            'value' => '2014-12-11', //The date what you want...
            'compare'   => '>='
        ),
    ),
));
```

Comment: I think he/she also needs `'compare'=>'>='` as posts equal or greater than are requested

Comment: That works a treat, thanks :) do you know if there's any way to do it with the broadcast-date being input in DD/MM/YYYY format?

Comment: I don't know, I don't think, but you can easily convert that with `strtotime` and `date` functions

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go and let you know how I get on. I'm more used to the js way of doing things, so I was thinking maybe something along the lines of splitting it broadcast-date by '/' and rearing the array items into a new variable. If I can't get strtotime to work, is something like my js method possible in php do you think?

Comment: `strtotime` is not good here, that was my bad. but you can use this, `$date = '24/12/2014';
$parts = explode('/',$date);
$newDate = $parts[2]."-".$parts[1]."-".$parts[0];`

Comment: I understand that code but I'm struggling to get it to work. I'm trying to get the broadcast-date for the first `$date` variable with `get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'broadcast-date', true );` but it returns 1970-01-01. If i leave it as '24/12/2014' it returns nothing. I'm putting your code in the top of my function, is that right? I've updated my question with my current code

Comment: Change `'value' => $todaysDate` to `'value' => $newDate`

Comment: Wouldn't I then be comparing the broadcast date with itself? The broadcast date is the one I want to split and rearrange to compare against todaysDate, which is already in YYYY/MM/DD format.

Comment: Oh you are right, but in this case, you do not need to use my date code. What if you try `$todaysDate = date("Y-m-d");` I don't think this will help, but give a shot.

Comment: I can't get my head around how it's comparing two totally different date formats, but it works!

Thanks for your help lolka, you've been a life saver! :)